# Update all field values that match a criteria

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to change the value of author where the value is lower than 0 
I use this but no result :

```
db.posts.update({author:{$lt:0}},{$set:{author:582127753}})
```

any Ideas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From the Mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/)-

> By default, the update() method updates a single document that
>   matches its selection criteria. Call the method with the multi option
>   set to true to update multiple documents.

So you should run your query like this:

```
db.posts.update(
  {author:{$lt:0}},
  {$set:{author:582127753}},
  { multi: true }
)
```